# A question about Google Play Billing. Getting subscription details

Tags: in-app-purchase, subscription, billing

I want to implement in the application 1 subscription with 2 Base Plans (1 month, 1 year).
And I can't get subscription deatails.
I request active purchases(subscriptions) but cannot get information about the current subscription(name and time of expiration). I get only orderId and purchaseToken.

I use the queryPurchasesAsync function, which returns valid purchases, but information about the end of the subscription, the base plan ID and other information. According to the Google documentation, the methods are deprecated.
Google's documentation says that you need to access the REST Api directly.
Is there a way to do this bypassing the REST Api? How are they doing now?